# Can I block a syslog message with iptables

Tags: iptables, syslog

I've got a few firewalls that I don't personally manage sending junk syslog messages through my ubuntu machine (which acts as a software router).  Is there an easy way for me to block forwarding a particular syslog message (by some text) like I would with with rsyslog or syslog-ng rules using iptables.

Comment: Not with stock iptables, as it only works on layer 3 and doesn't do deep packet inspection.

Answer (score 1):

You could write something horrible with [`-m u32 --u32`](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbCK) to do this, but iptables really isn't meant to operate at this level, so it'd be really ugly, and probably inefficient and/or unreliable too.